# make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'posix'. Stop

Tags: makefile

Been trying for hours trying to fix errors so that i can download this makefile
but haven't been able to find answers to my errors "posix" the makefile code is below. I need help.

```make
CC := gcc

ifeq ($(debug), y)
    CFLAGS := -g
else
    CFLAGS := -O2 -DNDEBUG
endif

CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-E -Wall -Werror -fPIC

LUADIR := $(HOME)/workspace/lua

INCLUDE := -I$(LUADIR)/src
LIBS := -L$(LUADIR)/src -llua -lmysqlclient -lm -ldl

TARGET := luamysql luamysql.so

.PHONY: all clean deps

all: deps $(TARGET)

luamysql: luamysql.o host.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

luamysql.so: luamysql.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -shared -o $@ $(LIBS)

deps:
    $(MAKE) posix MYCFLAGS="-fPIC -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN -Wl,-E" MYLIBS="-ldl" -C $(LUADIR)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.o
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There is only one `posix` in the Makefile (at `deps`), so `posix` should exist already.

Comment: Errors = https://i.imgur.com/3Zl4mlF.png

Comment: Here is the download https://github.com/ouonline/lua-mysql